# Marshal field as a value attribute of a subnode with field's name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

A smart person somewhere has designed an xml like this:

```
<node>
  <subnode value="sv1"/>
  <anotherSubNode value="asv" />
</node>
```

I would like to map this to POJO object looking like this:

```
class Node {
  String subnode;
  String anotherSubNode;
  //...
}
```

Instead of

```
class NodeValue {
  @XmlAttribute
  String value;
}
class Node {
  NodeValue subnode;
  NodeValue anotherSubNode;
  /...
}
```

Is there a way I can efficiently do this with standard java xml marshaling? Or even non-standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) is the simplest and most generic solution. An adapter for String field would look like that:

```
public class NodeValueStringAttrMarshaller extends XmlAdapter<NodeValueElement, String> {

    @Override
    public NodeValueElement marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return new NodeValueElement(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(NodeValueElement v) throws Exception {
        if (v==null) return "";
        return v.getValue();
    }

}
```

If you have fields of other types, like Long or Boolean, you would have to implement other (equally simple) adapters.

A generic field-object to marshal to will also be necessary:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class NodeValueElement {

    @XmlAttribute(name="value")
    String value;

    public NodeValueElement() {
    }

    public NodeValueElement(String value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

To use the adapter you have to annotate appropriate fields in your POJO:

```
class Node {
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=NodeValueStringAttrMarshaller.class)
  String subnode;

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=NodeValueLongAttrMarshaller.class)
  Long anotherSubNode;
  //...
}
```